# Fail to run project with Xcode 9 , Many new C++ semantic issue

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode

My project works fine in Xcode 8. When I build It in Xcode 9, there are many C++ semantic issues reported.It seems Xcode 9 C++ complier do much stricter type checking than Xcode 8.Is there a build configure fix to this.
[image]

Comment: Why are you doing *ordered* comparisons between pointers and zero? Should these not be equal, or not equal, comparisons (i.e. equality tests against nil)? Probably better to fix these rather than look for option to suppress the errors.

Comment: Try to search option in project settings to switch of treating warnings as errors.

Comment: I have fix those ambiguous code In my code as well as third-party frameworks. as @CRD say, fix semantic issues is a better solution to avoid potential errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three little lines in the upper right of the error list. Like an icon of lines of text. Click those to get the raw compiler output for your error messages. At the end of each warning it usually names the command-line flag corresponding to it (like [-Wwarn-about-mistakes]). You can search for that in build settings using the filter field to see the corresponding check box.

All that said: all these warnings have a reason for being there. You should find out what each warning is about and change your code the right way so the compiler doesn't  have to warn anymore.

Even if these warnings seem pointless and your code appears to work, they usually indicate an issue that is either already occurring, or might have unexpected side effects later when you change another part of your code.